# VIM Background - Terminal left a Border?

Tags: vim, terminal

when i running Terminal-VIM in fullscreen-mode with a Colorscheme there are still a small border from the standard terminal background color.You can see right and down.

Is there a easy way to fix this that there are always the background color from the scheme i use? Or a easy way with the vimrc ?

[image]

best regards

Comment: So this only happens in full-screen mode? What OS?

Comment: Does it happen with all color schemes? My first guess would be that you're usung a color scheme that specifies a different color for the status bar. I tried a few color schemes here on Ubuntu and some of them clearly do this.

Comment: Also, it's pretty difficult to determine anything from the image you've shared. Are you talking about the purple running up and down the entire right side of the image? It would help a lot if you could zoom in on the color you're talking about (or maybe use some colors that contrast with each other).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Iam using Ubuntu 13.04 and the puprle color you can see right and down (the color who is not grey... thats my colorscheme from wombat256) is the standard terminal color. So yes, it happens with all colorschemes and only when i running fullscren or maximizing the terminal window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only fix is to have your terminal and vim's background use the same color. Or make vim not have a background color.

Some terminals like urxvt allow you to define the width of that gutter, maybe your terminal does too.